# Put a promise in a pending state

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to defer the execution of a Promise, until user input is provided.

I want do a post, but wait until something has happened, like this:

```
while (true) {
  promiseForUserInput = pending;
  strInput = rl.question("provide input"); //waits for user input
  promiseForUserInput = resolved;
  var resultOfUsersChoice = promiseForUserInput.then(function(input) {
    return loadFromServer(input)
  }).then(function(serverResponse) {
    console.log(serverResponse)
  });
}
```

Is it possible? Do I need to read up on factory functions?

Comment: In your code, `rl.question("provide input")` will block the execution and wait for input. Do you want to wait till you get response from the server and then prompt the user again?

Comment: Yes @thefourtheye, I want to prompt the user again

Answer (score 1):

That would have to work something like this:

```
new Promise(function (resolve) {
    document.getElementById('my-input').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        if (/* input value is good enough for you */) {
            resolve(e.currentTarget.value);
        }
    });
})
```

To get the input (I'm assuming a browser context here), you have to bind an event listener to some input element and read the input from the element upon some decided event. You simply do all that inside the promise, and `resolve` the promise as soon as you're happy with the input value.

You can then `.then` this promise:

```
thePromise.then(function (input) {
    alert(input);
});
```

The input data will be the resolved value.

Comment: Thank you @deceze, I actually want to do this only from the node rs console input. But I get the Idea, I should have an outer Promise that includes all the promise calls, then I can do  a resolve on the array of promises that I have. Hope it works!

Comment: Not sure how that works under node, as you'll need an asynchronous input method somehow.